# There is no bijective function $g:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ , such that $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g(n)}{n^2}< \infty$ .

Tags: real-analysis, divergent-series, natural-numbers

**Question:** Prove that there is no bijective function $g:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ , such that $ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g(n)}{n^2}$$ < \infty$ .(This question is fromTIFR Mathematics, 2021)

**My attempt:**
*Since $g:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ is bijective, so $g(n_{1}) \neq g(n_2)$ $\Rightarrow n_1 \neq n_2$*.
Now g(n) gives a natural number . So we can write $g(n)= n^{x_n}$,  $\forall$ n>1 ; where $ x_n\in \Bbb R^+  $
Therefore,  $ \frac{g(n)}{n^2}$$=$$\frac{1}{n^{(2-{x_n})}} > \frac {1}{n^2}$ .
Now  , $\sum_{n}\frac {g(n)}{n^2}$ =$\sum_{n=2}\frac {1}{n^{(2-x_n)}}+g(1)$ > $\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^{(2-max.{{x_n}})}}+g(1)-1$ .
Now ,$\Biggr(\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^{(2-max.{x_n})}}+g(1)-1\Biggr)$  is divergent since  $(2-max.\{x_n\}) \le 1$ because there exist a pair $(m,n)\in\Bbb N ×\Bbb N$ such that $x_i=\log_n m \ge 1$ Therefore $max.\{x_n\}\ge 1$
and so is $\sum_{n}\frac {g(n)}{n^2}$ is *divergent*.
Hence $\sum_{n}\frac {g(n)}{n^2} \not\lt \infty$ .

Now I'm not sure whether $\sum_{n}\frac {g(n)}{n^2} \not\lt \infty$  can be written like this or not when the series is divergent .
For example we know $\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n}<\sum_{n}n$ , $\forall n\in\Bbb N $ here both the series of L.H.S and R.H.S are *divergent* but if we follow the *inequality* ,$\sum\frac{1}{n}<\infty$ .

Is my attempt to this problem correct ? If not please help to prove that.

Comment: "$g(n)$ gives a natural number. So we can write $g(n)=n^{x_n}$". Why can we do that?

Comment: I actually don't understand your proof completely but I think you rely on $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ to diverge when $\alpha < 2$. This is not the case. It converges for all $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: @Conifold let m&n be two Natural numbers so we can we write $ \log_n m= x$ for all natural numbers m and n ... here x is real number. That's why

Comment: @metamorphy yes you are right except injective function

Comment: @Conifold this not a duplicate question... the question asked earlier was on injective function but this is on Bijective function.  Plz let me show my solution.  Can u plz unclose the question

Comment: @DebjitMullick: A bijective function is in particular injective. The other Q&A demonstrates that there is no injective function such that the series converges. That is a stronger result than what you are asking for. There is no need to reopen the question.

Comment: Any bijective function is injective, so solution there applies here. Only moderators can unclose a question, they have diamonds next to their usernames. If want your argument checked rather than the question answered you should ask for *that* explicitly. I do not think it works. What you need is some sort of estimate on how fast $g(n)$ grows, but all you are doing is just rewriting it in terms of $x_n$, so the issue shifts to that. Why does $\max x_n$ exist? Even if it does but $<1$ then $2-\max x_n>1$ and your estimating series will not be divergent.

Comment: @Conifold I think there exist (m,n)$\in\Bbb NX\Bbb N$ such that $\log_n m \ge 1$ . Then max$\x_n \ge 1$ ... Although I have no rigorous proof of that ... but I didn't find any counter to this also... if you find any counter plz help ... thus I wrote ... Yes I made a mistake just by saying "(2-xn)<2 that's why it's divergent... " .. I'm editing my answer.  Thank you